# css overflow: hidden cause mouse layerX & layerY position incorrect

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, overflow

I'm creating context menu using Vuejs `@contextmenu.prevent` api. But when clicking on element with `overflow:hidden` style it cause `event.layerX` & `event.layerY` in wrong position.

```js
new Vue({ 
  el:'#app', 
  data: { 
    menuStyle: { top: '0px', left: '0px' },
    menuOpen:false 
  }, 
  methods: { 
    onContextMenu(e){ 
      console.log('contextmenuevent',e) 
      this.menuStyle = {
        top: `${e.layerY}px`,
        left: `${e.layerX}px`
      }
      this.menuOpen = true
    } 
  } 
})
```

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app" class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div
        id="item"
        class="p-8 bg-green-200 flex items-center"
        @contextmenu.prevent="onContextMenu"
      >
        <div class="w-20 bg-red-200 truncate p-2">
          Click me lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
        <div class="non-overflow">Non overflow</div>
      </div>
      <div
        v-if="menuOpen"
        id="menu"
        :style="menuStyle"
        class="bg-white shadow p-4 absolute absolute"
      >
        this is menu
        <button @click="menuOpen = false" class="bg-red-200 p-1">close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/showcheap/pen/YzPBmgp

Note: I'm using tailwindcss for styling

Comment: Use `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` instead (see [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rNaRNYG)).

Comment: Thanks @tony19 I thought it's not exists, because I only see clientX,Y and layerX,Y on console log. 

`contextmenu { target: div.w-20.bg-red-200.truncate.p-2, buttons: 2, clientX: 272, clientY: 88, layerX: 272, layerY: 88 }`

Comment: `clientX` and `cllientY` would work as well. Note that `layerX` and `layerY` are non-standard APIs and not recommended for production.

Comment: `clientX` and `clientY` not work when page scrolled, the item bellow screen height wil have wrong context menu position. [demo](https://codepen.io/showcheap/pen/WNbmNaG?editors=1010)

Comment: Then use `pageX` and `pageY`